# C program crashes during run time

Tags: c

The problem statement is :

When the number is 64,253 is multiplied by 365 the product is 23,452,345. Notice that the
first four digits are the same as the last four digits (2345 and 2345). Write a program that will
find any and all integers that can be multiplied by 365 to produce an eight-digit product where
the first four digits are the same as the last four digits.
In the example above, no digits were repeated, but in your program, the product can have
repetition. For example, 44,884,488. (Hint: Use mod)

The code I have written is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int a=10000, b,c;
// 64253
while(a<100000){

    b = a*365;
    c = (a*365)%10000;

    if(c == 0 || b %1000 == c)
        continue;

    if(b/c == 10001 ){
        printf("%d \n",a);
    }

    ++a;
}


return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why it crashes. Can you friends help?

Comment: Where does it crash and what's the error message?

Comment: I see no reason why it should crash (no overflow if int is 32 bits) but I doubt you'll get correct results.

Comment: It says process returned 255 (0XFF).

Comment: I do not see anything obvious. You need to run this under debugger. Also, please clarify "crashes". Are there any messages printed?

Comment: Please run this from command prompt and cut/paste the output

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Unix?

Comment: I am using Windows and I still get the crash which I will explain but I am currently using Code Blocks. I get now a blank screen in command window which shows nothing. Please check the updated code. Yes I will run on Command prompt as well and let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(10000*365) % 10000` is 0.

So you're dividing: `b/0` which results in a Floating Point Exception.

EDIT: Note that this answer is prior to OP edit, before the `c == 0` check was introduced in the example code.

Answer (score 3):

When `c` is zero, you try to divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, when `a` is a multiple of 10000, you divide by 0 afterward.
Anyway, it might not matter to you, but you could put a check like:

```
if(b/10000000<0 || b/10000000>9)continue;
```

To optimize the code. (This way you eliminate all the not-8 digit numbers).